# Python parse text and group into different parts

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've a text like the following

1. This is a first question and can go to multiple paragraphs.
   Multiple lines. etc.
   (1)First Option   (2) Second Option (3) Third option (4) Fourth Option (5) None of these
2. 8 × ? = 4888 ÷ 4
   (1) 150.75  (2) 125.75  (3) 125.05  (4) 152.75  (5) None of these
3. (62.5 × 14 × 5) ÷ 25 + 41 =
   (1) 4   (2) 5   (3) 9   (4) 8   (5) 6
4. (23 × 23 × 23 × 23 × 23 × 23)×
   (1) 32  (2) 30  (3) 9   (4) 7   (5) 11

I would like to parse this into different parts so that I can iterate in a for loop and get each question and also iterate over each answers.
The rule is that every question will start with an integer at the start of line (^) followed by a dot. The answers will be prefixed by integers 1 to 5 surrounded by brackets (1-5).

I would like the parsed data say for ex something like:

```
for item in parsed_data:
    print item.text
    for answer in item.answers:
        print answer.text
```

How to do this using python regex?

Comment: You are almost certainly better off looking at PyParsing in lieu of a regex IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly, you can just use `re.split()` for this:

```
#text is the variable with your text
text = text.strip()
questions = re.split(r'\d+\.',text)
questions = [x.strip() for x in questions if x != '']
final = [re.split(r'\(\d+\)',x) for x in questions]

for part in final:
    question = part[0]
    print question
    for answer in part[1:]:
        print answer
```

Comment: Don't forget to import `re` module.

Comment: You are close. I'm ready to accept this answer if it can follow these rules:
A question is a text which has an integer at the start of the line followed by a dot. Preferable something with ^.
The answers also starts in a new line.

The above regex fails for the following:
19. 8 × ? = 4888 ÷ 4
(1) 150.75  (2) 125.75  (3) 125.05  (4) 152.75  (5) None of these

Comment: I've added a minor correction for suiting my purpose.
questions = re.split(r'\n\n\d+\.\ ',text)
Thank you and keep up the good work!